# My table is too long for the page

Tags: tables, captions

I am working on my thesis and am not a champion of Latex. I am making tables and 1 table gets cut off and does not continue on the next page. I already tried adjusting the width of the columns but the table is too big. I also seem to have a problem with the caption function, as it does not want to give my table a caption. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{.45\textwidth}p{.45\textwidth}}
\label{voorennadelen}
         \textbf{Advantages} &  \textbf{Sources}\\\midrule
        \underline{Health} \\
        \begin{enumerate}[itemsep = 0 mm]
            \item Decreased childhood disease
            \begin{enumerate}[itemsep = 0 mm]
           \item  Childhood pneumonia
            \item Chronic obstructive pulmonary
             \item  Lung cancer
             \item Asthma and Cataract
             \item Low birth weight and stillbirth
          \item Tuberculosis
            \end{enumerate}
            \item Decrease of 90-99 \% of Schistosomiasis
            \item Typically 50 \% inactivation of helminth eggs and modest (13 \%) reductions of tapeworm, roundworm, \textit{E. coli} and \textit{Enterococci}
            \item Solid retention times of 3 weeks at mesophilic conditions are enough to kill pathogens leading to typhoid, cholera, dysentery and hookworm

        \end{enumerate} & \begin{enumerate}[itemsep = 0 mm]
            \item \citet{desai} \citet{bruce} \citet{pope} \citet{Slama}
            \item \citet{ISATGTZ}
            \item \citet{remais} \citet{bond} \citet{gantzer}
            \item \citet{bond}
        \end{enumerate}\\
        \hline
        
        \underline{Agronomic}\\
        \begin{enumerate}[itemsep = 0 mm]
            \item Increased agricultural yields of 6–10 \% and sometimes up to 20 \% have been recorded through use of biogas slurry as fertiliser
            \item N and P are more easily accessible
            \item Reduction in certain weed seeds with a reduced need for herbicides
        \end{enumerate} & \begin{enumerate}[itemsep = 0 mm]
            \item \citet{ISATGTZ}
            \item \citet{Messner} \citet{Plaixats} \citet{masse2007} 
            \item \citet{masse2011}
        \end{enumerate}\\
        \hline
        
        \underline{Social}\\
        \begin{enumerate}[itemsep = 0 mm]
            \item Reduction of size and quantity of landfills 
            \item Less time collecting firewood (especially women and children) with as a consequence less physical stress on the body + more time for other things (free time for women to engage in other activities to benefit the household or community (i.e. fabrication of textiles, crafts, etc. to sell) as well as more free time for children to pursue formal education.) 
            \item People living away from centralised grid can get acces gas and electricity
            
        \end{enumerate} & \begin{enumerate}[itemsep = 0 mm]
            \item \citet{masse2011}
            \item \citet{liu2008}
            \item \citet{opportunitiesandchallengesdigesters}
        \end{enumerate}\\
        \hline
        \underline{Enviromental}\\
        \begin{enumerate}[itemsep = 0 mm]
            \item Reduction in deforestation (54\% of deforestation in developing nations) associated with firewood collection (Reduction of 84\% of firewood consumption in the Southern province of Sri Lanka)
            \item Reduced soil erosion
            \item Reduction of organic matter in effluent water (removal of +/- 90\% of soluble chemical O\textsubscript{2} demand and +/- 80\% of total O\textsubscript{2} demand)
            \item 24-50 \% reduction of N\textsubscript{2}O emissions
            \item Reduction in NH\textsubscript{3} emissions. 
            \item Reduction of zoonotic pathogens, such as Campylobacter, Salmonella, Yersinia enterocolitica, Cryptosporidium and Giardia are dangerous for water quality (but bioreactor design and operating strategy must have sufficient residence time to allow complete destruction of pathogens)
            \item Rough estimations say biogas technology could potentially reduce global anthropogenic methane emissions by around 4%
            \item Reduced demand for synthetic fertilisers caused by increased use of digested biomass as fertiliser could reduce emissions
            
        \end{enumerate} & \begin{enumerate}[itemsep = 0 mm]
            \item \citet{plugflowcostaricavarkenkak} \citet{liu2008} \citet{dealwis}
            \item \citet{plugflowcostaricavarkenkak} \citet{liu2008}
            \item \citet{plugflowcostaricavarkenkak}
            \item \cite{clemensamon}
            \item \citet{Chantigny2007}\citet{Chantigny2009}
            \item \citet{masse2011}
            \item \citet{ISATGTZ}
            \item \citet{bond}
        \end{enumerate}\\
        
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
```

And picture of the pdf
[image: Picture of the result in pdf where my table just gets cut of]

Comment: if it is smaller than a page (including the caption) your should let it float. If longer than a page you need something like `longtable` to make a table that can be broken over pages

Comment: Have you tried to use \pagebreak?

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your table, which reproduce your problem. Page layout, which is unknown, has strong influence on table size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you (still) not provide MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small but complete document similar to the suggested in this answer), so this answer consider

- for table `tabularray` package version 2021N
- page layout defined by `\usepackage[vmargin=25mm]{geometry}`
- used uneven column widths in the table
- used `\small` font size and reduced lines spread

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=25mm]{geometry}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx, varwidth}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep,
                    itemsep=0.5ex,    
                    leftmargin=*,
                    after=\end{minipage},                  % <---
                    before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % <---
                      }
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\alph*.}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z} = 1pt, hline{even} = {solid}, 
             vlines,
             colspec={X[2] X[1]},
             rows  = {font=\small\linespread{0.92}\selectfont},
             row{1}= {font=\bfseries},
             measure = vbox,
             }
Advantages          &   Sources         \\

\underline{Health}  &                   \\
    \begin{enumerate}
\item Decreased childhood disease

        \begin{enumerate}
    \item  Childhood pneumonia
    \item Chronic obstructive pulmonary
    \item  Lung cancer
    \item Asthma and Cataract
    \item Low birth weight and stillbirth
    \item Tuberculosis
        \end{enumerate}
\item Decrease of 90-99 \% of Schistosomiasis
\item Typically \qty{50}{\%} inactivation of helminth eggs and modest (\qty{13}{\%}) reductions of tapeworm, roundworm, \textit{E. coli} and \textit{Enterococci}
\item Solid retention times of 3 weeks at mesophilic conditions are enough to kill pathogens leading to typhoid, cholera, dysentery and hookworm
    \end{enumerate} &   \begin{enumerate}
                    \item \citet{desai} \citet{bruce} \citet{pope} \citet{Slama}
                    \item \citet{ISATGTZ}
                    \item \citet{remais} \citet{bond} \citet{gantzer}
                    \item \citet{bond}
                        \end{enumerate} \\
\underline{Agronomic}   &               \\
    \begin{enumerate}
\item Increased agricultural yields of \qtyrange{6}{10}{\%} and sometimes up to \qty{20}{\%} have been recorded through use of biogas slurry as fertiliser
\item N and P are more easily accessible
\item Reduction in certain weed seeds with a reduced need for herbicides
    \end{enumerate} &   \begin{enumerate}
                    \item \citet{ISATGTZ}
                    \item \citet{Messner} \citet{Plaixats} \citet{masse2007}
                    \item \citet{masse2011}
                        \end{enumerate} \\
\underline{Social}  &                   \\
    \begin{enumerate}
\item Reduction of size and quantity of landfills
\item Less time collecting firewood (especially women and children) with as a consequence less physical stress on the body + more time for other things (free time for women to engage in other activities to benefit the household or community (i.e. fabrication of textiles, crafts, etc. to sell) as well as more free time for children to pursue formal education.)
\item People living away from centralised grid can get access gas and electricity
    \end{enumerate} &   \begin{enumerate}
            \item \citet{masse2011}
            \item \citet{liu2008}
            \item \citet{opportunitiesandchallengesdigesters}
                        \end{enumerate} \\
\underline{Enviromental}    &           \\
    \begin{enumerate}
\item Reduction in deforestation (\qty{54}{\%} of deforestation in developing nations) associated with firewood collection (Reduction of \qty{84}{\%} of firewood consumption in the Southern province of Sri Lanka)
\item Reduced soil erosion
\item Reduction of organic matter in effluent water (removal of \qty{\pm 90}{\%} of soluble chemical \ce{O2} demand and \qty{\pm 80}{\%} of total \ce{O2} demand)
\item 24-50 \% reduction of \ce{N2O} emissions
\item Reduction in \ce{NH3} emissions.
\item Reduction of zoonotic pathogens, such as Campylobacter, Salmonella, Yersinia enterocolitica, Cryptosporidium and Giardia are dangerous for water quality (but bioreactor design and operating strategy must have sufficient residence time to allow complete destruction of pathogens)
\item Rough estimations say biogas technology could potentially reduce global anthropogenic methane emissions by around 4%
\item Reduced demand for synthetic fertilisers caused by increased use of digested biomass as fertiliser could reduce emissions
    \end{enumerate} &   \begin{enumerate}
                    \item \citet{plugflowcostaricavarkenkak} \citet{liu2008} \citet{dealwis}
                    \item \citet{plugflowcostaricavarkenkak} \citet{liu2008}
                    \item \citet{plugflowcostaricavarkenkak}
                    \item \cite{clemensamon}
                    \item \citet{Chantigny2007}\citet{Chantigny2009}
                    \item \citet{masse2011}
                    \item \citet{ISATGTZ}
                    \item \citet{bond}
                        \end{enumerate}         \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout).

I the case that above assumption are wrong, that you should use long table, for example `\longtblr` and could have standard `article layout:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[vmargin=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx, varwidth}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep,
                    itemsep=0.5ex,    
                    leftmargin=*,
                    leftmargin=*,
                    after=\end{minipage},                  % <---
                    before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % <---
                      }
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\alph*.}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption={My long table},
    label={tab:longtable}
                ]{
    hline{1,Z} = 1pt, hline{even} = {solid}, 
    vlines,
    colspec={X[2] X[1]},
    rows  = {font=\small\linespread{0.92}\selectfont},
    row{1}= {font=\bfseries},
    measure = vbox,
             }
% table body, the same as before
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! The longtable works perfectly.

Comment: @Aaron, if it really work perfectly, than you can accept my answer (by clicking on checkmark at top left side of answer) :-)